# i want to sent order id in the api url and get proper response in the json?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

> Response : {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://example.com/Api/WooCommerceApi/SaveSubscriptionAndZoomData'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'WooCommerceApi' that matches the request."}

Here is my Code to send order in in the api url

```
function my_api_call( $order_id ){

// Order Setup Via WooCommerce

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

// Iterate Through Items

$items = $order->get_items();

$url = "http://example.com/Api/WooCommerceApi/SaveSubscriptionAndZoomData";

$orderid = "OrderId=".$order_id;

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $orderid);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

 write_log ("Order Id for new user: " .$orderid ." and Response is : ".$response);

 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'my_api_call');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is right there in the error message:

```
Response : {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://example.com/Api/WooCommerceApi/SaveSubscriptionAndZoomData'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'WooCommerceApi' that matches the request."}
```

A quick look through WC docs doesn't show any endpoints with that name, which is what the error message was telling you. Make sure you're calling an endpoint that actually exists in WC.